# Android Studio 1.1.0 "Cannot resolve symbol" error on @string values in manifest

Tags: android-studio

Having just renamed the directory in which my Android Studio project sits, AS is now confused about the values pulled from the res/values/strings.xml file into the manifest. They all have red errors on them: "Cannot resolve symbol...". The values definitely exist.

I've tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... No help. I've tried Clean Project. No help.

The run configuration for the app also has a red cross on it and says "Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Android Studio 1.2 has fixed this.